# Sending a Group of SMSes works on Emulator but not always on phone

Tags: android, sms

I'm developing some Android application which gets a group of SMSes via web service and sends them, it's implemented as the service, and is called every 2 minutes for example, via LogCat I could see that messages are retrieved and sent with sendTextMessage properly, but on phone it doesn't work all the time, I'm sure they get to phone from server but apparently sendTextMessage and sendMultipartTextMessage are not working, for example when it gets 4 SMSes to send it only sends one or two of them or sometimes none, it plays randomly, do you see where is my problem?

Service :

```
public class CopyOfSender extends Service {

    static final String KEY_ITEM_SMSList = "SMS";
    static final String KEY_Id = "Id";
    static final String KEY_Message = "Message";
    static final String KEY_Number = "Number";
    String SmsURL = "GetSMS/";
    String UpdateMessageStatuseURL = "UpdateSMSStatus";
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    String userNumner = "";
    String password = "";
    String smsPerSend = "20";
    Context thisContext = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        thisContext = getApplicationContext();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        if (pref.getString("smsPerSend", null) != null) {
            smsPerSend = pref.getString("smsPerSend", "");
        }
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        String BaseUrl = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(
                R.string.baseURl);
        SmsURL = BaseUrl + SmsURL;
        UpdateMessageStatuseURL = BaseUrl + UpdateMessageStatuseURL;
        wl.acquire();
        if (pref.getString("phonenumber", null) == null
                || pref.getString("password", null) == null) {

        } else {
            userNumner = pref.getString("phonenumber", "");
            password = pref.getString("password", "");
            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.noInternet),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                new SendSMS().execute();
            }
        }
        wl.release();
    }

    private class Message {
        public String Id;
        public String Message;
        public String Number;
    }

    private class SendSMS extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(SmsURL + "?number=" + userNumner
                    + "&password=" + password + "&count=" + smsPerSend);
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM_SMSList);
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                String tempId = parser.getValue(e, KEY_Id);
                String tempMessage = parser.getValue(e, KEY_Message);
                String tempNumber = parser.getValue(e, KEY_Number);
                Message tempSMS = new Message();
                tempSMS.Id = tempId;
                tempSMS.Message = tempMessage;
                tempSMS.Number = tempNumber;
                messages.add(tempSMS);
            }
            for (Message item : messages) {
                if (item.Number.trim().length() != 0) {
                    if (item.Message.trim().length() != 0) {
                        sendSMS(item.Number.trim(), item.Message.trim(),
                                Integer.parseInt(item.Id));
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            return;
        }
    }

    private class UpdateSMSStat extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

            int smsId = (Integer) arg0[0];
            int stat = (Integer) arg0[1];

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            List<NameValuePair> IdsToSend = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            IdsToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MessageIds", Integer
                    .toString(smsId)));
            IdsToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Status", Integer
                    .toString(stat)));
            IdsToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Number", userNumner));
            IdsToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", password));
            parser.sendPostRequest(UpdateMessageStatuseURL, IdsToSend);

            return null;
        }

    }

    private void sendSMS(final String phoneNumber, String message,
            final int messageId) {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(thisContext, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(thisContext, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        thisContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        thisContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    new UpdateSMSStat().execute(messageId, 1, phoneNumber);
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    new UpdateSMSStat().execute(messageId, 3, phoneNumber);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

        Pattern p = Pattern
                .compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+-=\\|`~{};':,.<>/?/[/]\" ]");
        boolean hasSpecialChar = p.matcher(message).find();
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

        if (hasSpecialChar) {
            if (message.length() > 70) {
                ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
                ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
                ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliverPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
                sentPis.add(sentPI);
                deliverPis.add(deliveredPI);
                sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentPis,
                        deliverPis);
            } else {
                sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message.toString(),
                        sentPI, deliveredPI);
            }
        } else {
            if (message.length() > 160) {
                ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
                ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
                ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliverPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
                sentPis.add(sentPI);
                deliverPis.add(deliveredPI);
                sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentPis,
                        deliverPis);
            } else {
                sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message.toString(),
                        sentPI, deliveredPI);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you just need to have a delay between sendSMS() calls:

```
        for (Message item : messages) {
            if (item.Number.trim().length() != 0) {
                if (item.Message.trim().length() != 0) {
                    sendSMS(item.Number.trim(), item.Message.trim(),
                            Integer.parseInt(item.Id));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(SOME_DELAY);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) { }
                }
            }
        }
```

Or if you want to be more accurate, then you can wait for the SENT broadcast and then send another SMS.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem in Chat application (smack) using xmpp protocol of openfire server. and i solved.

If your SMS is using connection with server. I think you have connection problem. You should create a **Bucket** at the time of **message send** like as:-

```
sendMessage(message)
{
   try
    { 
      // your message send code 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      // save your message in a local DB.
    }
}
```

So When Connection will be **Re-connect to server** then it will send all **bucket** message like as

```
connection.connect();

// here check to bucket.
// if there is any message 
// send all message 
// and delete all bucket message.

// else if there is not any message in bucket.
 // then bucket is empty so no message need to send.
```

Please follow this Logic. Your message never will be lost.

Also May be In emulator connection is Wire connection so that connection is not lost always and sending all messages.

And real android device can lost connection by network problem or other. mostly case in Wifi. and service is restarted.

Thank you!